# Aggregate Path elements with Timecodes / Timeranges

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I have the following code. Finally, I would like to summarize my original data. The overlapping periods should be summarized and the min/max dates should be output.

The following code gives the longest PATH for each ID. So far so good. Unfortunately, I don't know how to use the ID to specify the longest overall PATH depending on the group.

Original table:

| ID | DATEN | BEGINN_ZEITSTEMPEL | ENDE_ZEITSTEMPEL | GRUPPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Datensatz1A | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | Datensatz2A | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 | 2023-05-15 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 3 | Datensatz3A | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 | 2023-05-30 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 4 | Datensatz4A | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2023-05-29 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 5 | Datensatz5A | 2023-05-14 00:00:00 | 2023-05-15 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 6 | Datensatz1B | 2023-05-29 00:00:00 | 2023-05-30 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 7 | Datensatz2B | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-08-01 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 8 | Datensatz3B | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-09-01 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 9 | Datensatz4B | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 10 | Datensatz5B | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | 3 |

Final Table:

| START_ID | DATEN | BEGINN_ZEITSTEMPEL | ENDE_ZEITSTEMPEL | GRUPPE | PATH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Datensatz1A | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 2 -> 4 -> 3 -> 1 |
| 5 | Datensatz5A | 2023-05-14 00:00:00 | 2023-05-15 00:00:00 | 2 | 5 |
| 6 | Datensatz1B | 2023-05-29 00:00:00 | 2023-05-30 00:00:00 | 2 | 6 |
| 7 | Datensatz3B | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-09-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 9 -> 7 -> 8 |
| 10 | Datensatz5B | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 10 |

```
    WITH CTE as (
            Select 1 as ID, 'Datensatz1A' as Daten, TO_DATE('2023-05-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Beginn_Zeitstempel, TO_DATE('2023-06-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Ende_Zeitstempel, 1 as Gruppe FROM DUAL
            UNION Select 2 as ID, 'Datensatz2A' as Daten, TO_DATE('2023-04-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Beginn_Zeitstempel, TO_DATE('2023-05-15 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Ende_Zeitstempel, 1 as Gruppe FROM DUAL
            UNION Select 3 as ID, 'Datensatz3A' as Daten, TO_DATE('2023-03-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Beginn_Zeitstempel, TO_DATE('2023-05-30 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Ende_Zeitstempel, 1 as Gruppe FROM DUAL
            UNION Select 4 as ID, 'Datensatz4A' as Daten, TO_DATE('2023-02-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Beginn_Zeitstempel, TO_DATE('2023-05-29 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Ende_Zeitstempel, 1 as Gruppe FROM DUAL
            UNION Select 5 as ID, 'Datensatz5A' as Daten, TO_DATE('2023-05-14 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Beginn_Zeitstempel, TO_DATE('2023-05-15 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Ende_Zeitstempel, 2 as Gruppe FROM DUAL
            UNION Select 6 as ID, 'Datensatz1B' as Daten, TO_DATE('2023-05-29 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Beginn_Zeitstempel, TO_DATE('2023-05-30 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Ende_Zeitstempel, 2 as Gruppe FROM DUAL
            UNION Select 7 as ID, 'Datensatz2B' as Daten, TO_DATE('2023-05-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Beginn_Zeitstempel, TO_DATE('2023-08-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Ende_Zeitstempel, 3 as Gruppe FROM DUAL
            UNION Select 8 as ID, 'Datensatz3B' as Daten, TO_DATE('2023-05-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Beginn_Zeitstempel, TO_DATE('2023-09-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Ende_Zeitstempel, 3 as Gruppe FROM DUAL
            UNION Select 9 as ID, 'Datensatz4B' as Daten, TO_DATE('2023-05-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Beginn_Zeitstempel, TO_DATE('2023-06-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Ende_Zeitstempel, 3 as Gruppe FROM DUAL
            UNION Select 10 as ID, 'Datensatz5B' as Daten, TO_DATE('2021-05-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Beginn_Zeitstempel, TO_DATE('2022-06-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as Ende_Zeitstempel, 3 as Gruppe FROM DUAL
    ),
    RecursiveCTE (Start_ID, End_ID, Daten, Beginn_Zeitstempel, Ende_Zeitstempel, Gruppe, Path) AS (
        SELECT
            ID,
            ID,
            Daten,
            Beginn_Zeitstempel,
            Ende_Zeitstempel,
            Gruppe,
            CAST(ID AS VARCHAR2(100)) AS PATH
        FROM CTE
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM CTE c
            WHERE c.ID = CTE.ID
            AND c.Gruppe = CTE.Gruppe
            AND c.Beginn_Zeitstempel < CTE.Beginn_Zeitstempel
        )
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            r.Start_ID,
            c.ID,
            c.Daten,
            LEAST(r.Beginn_Zeitstempel, c.Beginn_Zeitstempel),
            GREATEST(r.Ende_Zeitstempel, c.Ende_Zeitstempel),
            c.Gruppe,
            r.Path || ' -> ' || c.ID AS Pfad
            --r.Path || c.ID AS PATH        
        FROM RecursiveCTE r
        JOIN CTE c ON r.End_ID <> c.ID
                    AND r.Gruppe = c.Gruppe
                    AND r.Ende_Zeitstempel >= c.Beginn_Zeitstempel
                    AND r.Ende_Zeitstempel <= c.Ende_Zeitstempel
                    AND INSTR(r.Path, c.ID) = 0
    ),
    -- SELECT    * from RecursiveCTE
    MaxPathCTE AS (
        SELECT
            Start_ID,
            Gruppe,
            MAX(PATH) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY LENGTH(PATH)) AS MAX_PATH
        FROM RecursiveCTE
        GROUP BY Start_ID, Gruppe
    )
    SELECT
        r.Start_ID,
        r.Daten,
        r.Beginn_Zeitstempel,
        r.Ende_Zeitstempel,
        r.Gruppe,
        r.Path
    FROM RecursiveCTE r
    INNER JOIN MaxPathCTE m ON r.Start_ID = m.Start_ID AND r.Gruppe = m.Gruppe AND r.Path = m.MAX_PATH
    ORDER BY r.Start_ID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY Gruppe
  ORDER     BY Ende_Zeitstempel DESC, Beginn_Zeitstempel DESC
  MEASURES
    FIRST(id) AS start_id,
    LAST(ID) AS last_id,
    COUNT(*) AS num_rows,
    FIRST(daten) AS daten,
    MIN(Beginn_Zeitstempel) AS Beginn_Zeitstempel,
    FIRST(Ende_Zeitstempel) AS Ende_Zeitstempel
  PATTERN (overlapping* non_overlapping)
  DEFINE
    overlapping AS MIN(Beginn_Zeitstempel) <= NEXT(Ende_Zeitstempel)
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, daten, Beginn_Zeitstempel, Ende_Zeitstempel, Gruppe) AS
  Select  1, 'Datensatz1A', DATE '2023-05-01', DATE '2023-06-01', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  2, 'Datensatz2A', DATE '2023-04-01', DATE '2023-05-15', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  3, 'Datensatz3A', DATE '2023-03-01', DATE '2023-05-30', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  4, 'Datensatz4A', DATE '2023-02-01', DATE '2023-05-29', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  5, 'Datensatz5A', DATE '2023-05-14', DATE '2023-05-15', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  6, 'Datensatz1B', DATE '2023-05-29', DATE '2023-05-30', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  7, 'Datensatz2B', DATE '2023-05-01', DATE '2023-08-01', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  8, 'Datensatz3B', DATE '2023-05-01', DATE '2023-09-01', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  9, 'Datensatz4B', DATE '2023-05-01', DATE '2023-06-01', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select 10, 'Datensatz5B', DATE '2021-05-01', DATE '2022-06-01', 3 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| GRUPPE | START_ID | LAST_ID | NUM_ROWS | DATEN | BEGINN_ZEITSTEMPEL | ENDE_ZEITSTEMPEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 | Datensatz1A | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 6 | 6 | 1 | Datensatz1B | 2023-05-29 00:00:00 | 2023-05-30 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 5 | 5 | 1 | Datensatz5A | 2023-05-14 00:00:00 | 2023-05-15 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 8 | 9 | 3 | Datensatz3B | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-09-01 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 10 | 10 | 1 | Datensatz5B | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 |

If you want all the rows with the summary data:

```sql
SELECT m.*,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY gruppe, match_num) AS total_rows
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY Gruppe
  ORDER     BY Ende_Zeitstempel DESC, Beginn_Zeitstempel DESC
  MEASURES
    FIRST(id) AS start_id,
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS match_num,
    LAST(ID) AS last_id,
    COUNT(*) AS match_index,
    FIRST(daten) AS first_daten,
    MIN(Beginn_Zeitstempel) AS min_Beginn_Zeitstempel,
    FIRST(Ende_Zeitstempel) AS first_Ende_Zeitstempel
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (overlapping* non_overlapping)
  DEFINE
    overlapping AS MIN(Beginn_Zeitstempel) <= NEXT(Ende_Zeitstempel)
) m
```

Which outputs:

| GRUPPE | ENDE_ZEITSTEMPEL | BEGINN_ZEITSTEMPEL | START_ID | MATCH_NUM | LAST_ID | MATCH_INDEX | FIRST_DATEN | MIN_BEGINN_ZEITSTEMPEL | FIRST_ENDE_ZEITSTEMPEL | ID | DATEN | TOTAL_ROWS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | Datensatz1A | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 1 | Datensatz1A | 4 |
| 1 | 2023-05-30 00:00:00 | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 | Datensatz1A | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 3 | Datensatz3A | 4 |
| 1 | 2023-05-29 00:00:00 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 3 | Datensatz1A | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 4 | Datensatz4A | 4 |
| 1 | 2023-05-15 00:00:00 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 | Datensatz1A | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 2 | Datensatz2A | 4 |
| 2 | 2023-05-30 00:00:00 | 2023-05-29 00:00:00 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 1 | Datensatz1B | 2023-05-29 00:00:00 | 2023-05-30 00:00:00 | 6 | Datensatz1B | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-05-15 00:00:00 | 2023-05-14 00:00:00 | 5 | 2 | 5 | 1 | Datensatz5A | 2023-05-14 00:00:00 | 2023-05-15 00:00:00 | 5 | Datensatz5A | 1 |
| 3 | 2023-09-01 00:00:00 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 8 | 1 | 8 | 1 | Datensatz3B | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-09-01 00:00:00 | 8 | Datensatz3B | 3 |
| 3 | 2023-08-01 00:00:00 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 8 | 1 | 7 | 2 | Datensatz3B | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-09-01 00:00:00 | 7 | Datensatz2B | 3 |
| 3 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 8 | 1 | 9 | 3 | Datensatz3B | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-09-01 00:00:00 | 9 | Datensatz4B | 3 |
| 3 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | 10 | 2 | 10 | 1 | Datensatz5B | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | 10 | Datensatz5B | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RFjIMeE8)

Comment: one question. Your answer is really great; but hosw its possible to get neighboar attributes from the min time value ? 

The First and Last Function relates to the order by Ende_Zeitstempel.

I.e. i want in the 1 the solution with "Datensatz4A" not "Datensatz1A".

and the function.

MIN(daten) keep (dense_rank first order by (Beginn_Zeitstempel)) as daten,

is unfortunately not possible in this case :(

Comment: @Paddymaster Are these what you are looking for [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zMXnSxYJ)?

Comment: Well. ITs really good. One Question about your solution. The First one with First and Last is more performant as the second one ?  And the second one is more precisely  ?

Comment: @Paddymaster The second option in that fiddle lets you use `MAX(...) KEEP (DENSE_RANK ...)` and other aggregation functions such as `LISTAGG` which are not supported by `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`. If you only want the output from the first option then use that (yes, it will be more performant); if you want to get results that can only be partially achieved using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` then use/modify the second option.

Comment: my brain is slowly today. Faster is standard Match_recognize. Slower and more precisely is max (keep dense rank) etc.. ?

Comment: @Paddymaster More performant would be `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` with the default `ONE ROW PER MATCH` and aggregating within the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`. Less performant would be using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` with `ALL ROWS PER MATCH` and then adding a `GROUP BY` step afterwards to perform the aggregation but that does allow you to use aggregation functions that are not supported in `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`. There are benefits and drawbacks to both methods and you should use whichever is most appropriate to your business case.

Comment: Thk you very much :) you saved my day